# Codeigniter Custom Form Validation Rules

Tags: php, codeigniter

i'm trying to make a custom validation rules for a field. It's a multiple checkbox.

```
<div class="row checkbox-wrapper" id="checkbox-wrapper">
   <?php foreach ($facilities as $facility) : ?>
      <div class="col-md-6 mb-2">
         <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="list_facility[]" value="<?php echo $facility['id']; ?>">
            <label class="custom-control-label"><?php echo $facility['facility_name'] ?></label>
         </div>
      </div>
   <?php endforeach ?>
</div>
```

So i try to validate them with a custom rule called *facility_valdation()*

`$this->form_validation->set_rules('list_facility', 'Facility List', 'callback_facility_validation');`

```
public function facility_validation($array)
{
   if ($array == NULL) {
      $this->form_validation->set_message('facility_validation', 'Fasilitas tidak boleh kosong (minimal = 1)');
      return FALSE;
   } else {
      return TRUE;
   }
}
```

The false condition is correct, whenever i leave the checkbox empty, it returns the message. but if i try to check one or more box, i keep getting the false message.

I've tried to var_dump my list_facility variable and i already get what i want. It is NULL when there are no checkbox checked, or an array of id for every checkbox i checked.

I've implemented the custoiom validation in another controller and it works just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form input field is array, so your validate field must be an array too. It should be

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('list_facility[]', 'Facility List', 'callback_facility_validation');
```

`list_facility[]` instead of `list_facility`

I've tried and it works. Hope this helps

Comment: @cah-kangkung you're welcome. Could you please mark my answer as accepted answer? Then other users known that this question in resolved and ... that's my motivation :D